# Is there any way to keep my mouse moving continuously? (without using mouse jigglers)

Tags: windows, mouse, automation, autohotkey

There is an app that continously monitors all the other apps that I'm using, but it only registers me to be "working" if my mouse/keyboard is moving. So is there any way to get my mouse to move or my keyboardto press some key so that it detects me as "working" ?

I can't use any third party apps as the monitoring app also detects those apps running in the background.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is too little information about your work situation, but if you truly want to stick to software, you'll have to be thinking outside of the box.... literally.

If you can do your work inside a VM or connect to your computer using remote desktop from another computer, you can technically run software on a computer that your work cannot monitor.

This can then create mouse input that is as real as having anything move the actual mouse.

That said, keep in mind that the best way to know if someone is working, is to just check what work they completed. A boss is more likely to question your productivity by how much work you get done, than if you move your mouse or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not admitting I have done this before (LOL). 1) Open Notepad 2) Get a piece of paper and fold a small piece of it about 3-4 times. Stick between spacebar and the gap (frame) in front. You should see the cursor move forward like you are holding down the spacebar. Then you should be able to open other apps (like Teams) and it will show you are "available" !! This works until you remove the paper jam from keyboard, at the end of your shift.

Comment: You can also make a meeting with yourself and join it so that it shows that you are in a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be quite what you are looking for, but this mouse "jiggler" sends a mouse event while the mouse pointer itself stays in place.

```
SetTimer, Alive, 480000          ; Run every 8 minutes.
Return
 
Alive:
{
     MouseMove, 0, 0, 0, R       ; Mouse pointer stays in place but sends a mouse event.
;        Soundbeep, 1600, 100        ;  Uncomment for activity verification.
}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

This device is perfect for what you are wanting.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0B1MC3XKS/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B0B1MC3XKS&ref_=sbv_store_search&pd_rd_w=EE2IL&content-id=amzn1.sym.9d7662ad-a2af-4a26-8f03-bcbf0df0ef0a%3Aamzn1.sym.9d7662ad-a2af-4a26-8f03-bcbf0df0ef0a&pf_rd_p=9d7662ad-a2af-4a26-8f03-bcbf0df0ef0a&pf_rd_r=X9P3VE2F65FNGY8W746X&pd_rd_wg=RCEdW&pd_rd_r=9bf2af5f-8332-4674-b2dd-212b5824df48&pd_rd_plhdr=t&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B1MC3XKS)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1221045)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a laser mouse, you can try to install it on a clock, the moving needle and perpetual changes of position will trigger the detection.